# Hibernate sessionFactory bean throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
I am migrating jdbc to hibernate and i have palced below hibernate configuration in my application.

public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.cm.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcurl);
        dataSource.setUsername(userName);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        return properties;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

my application interacting fine with database at application startup creating hibernate session successfully through session factory giving output also.

```
**@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;**

protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

but after application startup when i hitting DAO by controller then session factory bean getting Null reference and throwing NullPointerException due to which unable to create or open hibernate session , i tried to find out solution but that's not working please let me know why above SessionFactory bean having nullPointer due to which issue created.

Just to test my DAO logic I am using this controller and This controller hitting to DAO where sessionFacory bean is null.

```
@RestController
        @RequestMapping("/Emp")
        public class myController {
          @RequestMapping(value = "/findByChannelManager", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public void findemp() {

                HotelDaoImpl hotelDaoImpl=new HotelDaoImpl();
                List <HotelEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list = hotelDaoImpl.findByChannelManager (EnumCM.AR);
                for (HotelEntity pro : list) {
                    System.out.println(pro);
            }
        }
    }


@Repository
@Transactional
public class HotelDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements IHotelDao {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @Override
    public List<HotelEntity> findByChannelManager(EnumCM cm) {
        List<HotelEntity> list = null;
        try {
        Session s = getSession();
        Criteria criteria=s.createCriteria(Hotel.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("channelManager", "cm.name()"));
        list = criteria.list();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug("error " +e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return list;
    }

public abstract class AbstractDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you update controller class?

Comment: can you update in post, `hotelDaoImpl=new HotelDaoImpl()` this might be cause, and also update `findByChannelManager` method code also

Comment: @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/Emp")
    public class myController {
      @RequestMapping(value = "/findByChannelManager", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void findemp() {

            HotelDaoImpl hotelDaoImpl=new HotelDaoImpl();

            List<HotelEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list=hotelDaoImpl.findByChannelManager(EnumCM.AR);
            for (HotelEntity pro : list) {
                System.out.println(pro);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Just to test my DAO logic I am using this controller and This controller hitting to DAO where sessionFacory bean is null.

Comment: you are creating `HotelDaoImpl` using `new` keyword,  do `@Autowired` `HotelDaoImpl` class in `@Controller` class

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'hotelDaoImpl': No qualifying bean of type , to resolve this issue i created Object instead of bean , in my application bean dependency issue i am facing by autowiring it.

Comment: annotate this class `hotelDaoImpl` with `@Service`

Comment: please try to update complete code so that it will be easy to look at it and help

Comment: updated with complete code

Comment: annotate `public abstract class AbstractDao` with @Service and Autowire `HotelDaoImpl ` in Controller

Comment: @Deadpool   no luck.

Comment: Update the code what ever you are doing with packages

Comment: Every thing is fine issue is with why sessionfacory bean pointing  to null in AbstactDAO.java

Comment: Can you try this, copy the code in abstractdao to hoteldaoimpl, and remove that extends abstractdao

Comment: I tried Still SessionFactory pointing to Null.Please let me know if any configuration is missing , any miss with associating hibernate session with Spring MVC Context or any lack of spring and hibernate Integration issue.

Comment: Have you declared sessionFactory as bean?

Comment: yes as LocalsessionFactory in hibernate Configuration , please check my Hibernate configuration file as in question and let me know if configuration issue with sessionfactory.

Comment: Issue got resolved as i was not able to create bean on controller due to inter dependency of bean in my code and testing of DAO i used object by new code on controller which was root cause by removing it issue resolved  , thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access dao from your controller. You can access dao from service so add service class. Try this code

```
@RestController
        @RequestMapping("/Emp")
        public class myController {
@Autowired
HotelService service;
          @RequestMapping(value = "/findByChannelManager", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public void findemp() {


                List <HotelEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list = service.findByChannelManager (EnumCM.AR);
                for (HotelEntity pro : list) {
                    System.out.println(pro);
            }
        }
    }
@Service
@Transactional
public class HotelService {
@Autowired
private HotelDao dao;

public List<HotelEntity> findByChannelManager(EnumCM cm) {
   return dao.findByChannelManager(EnumCM cm);
}
}

@Repository
public class HotelDaoImpl extends AbstractDao implements IHotelDao {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
    @Override
    public List<HotelEntity> findByChannelManager(EnumCM cm) {
        List<HotelEntity> list = null;
        try {
        Session s = getSession();
        Criteria criteria=s.createCriteria(Hotel.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("channelManager", "cm.name()"));
        list = criteria.list();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug("error " +e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return list;
    }

public abstract class AbstractDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    }
```